# Can I get some help modifying this Snowflake Javascript stored procedure to take in columns with spaces and other characters

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to preface this by saying I do not have much experience writing in python or JavaScript. I was able to fumble and work my way into writing this script.

I have a pipeline in ADF that calls this stored procedure. I feed it the five parameters and it loads flat files from our blob storage.

This has worked well for quite sometime and I'm honestly pretty happy with it. However, we are now ingesting some tables from SQL server (since ADF forces us to convert tables to flat files and then load to snowflake) due to the fact that they have 'Column Names With Spaces Like This' or 'Columns that look like <>#'. I've tried using chatgpt to help me with code but I just cant quite piece it together.

The code takes the primary key either does a load if the record does not exist, or updates the record if it is different than what exists. Pretty basic, nothing too crazy. The stored procedure lives in snowflake. We parametrize the loads and load 20+ tables at a time. I'm open to other ideas on how this can be done.

The following is the code:

```
--original script
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE DB_BI_DEV.STATE_CONFIG.BLOBTOSNOWFLAKE(
      "STG_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216),
      "FILE_PATH" VARCHAR(16777216),
      "FILE_FRMT" VARCHAR(16777216),
      "TBL_SCHEMA_NAME" VARCHAR(16777216),
      "SF_TBL" VARCHAR(16777216)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(16777216) 
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT 
EXECUTE AS OWNER AS '

// Intialize parameters
var single_quote=''\\'''';
var SCHEMA=TBL_SCHEMA_NAME;
var Destination_Table=SF_TBL;
var Source_Table="@"+STG_NAME+"/"+FILE_PATH+" (file_format =>"+single_quote+FILE_FRMT+single_quote+")  ";

// First script to count number of columns and append $ to support querying external stage files

var Blob_Columns_Query="SELECT CONCAT("+single_quote+"$"+single_quote
            +",LISTAGG(CONCAT(ORDINAL_POSITION,"+single_quote+" AS "+single_quote+",COLUMN_NAME),"+single_quote+",$"+single_quote
            +") WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) ) \\n FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS \\nWHERE TABLE_NAME="
            +single_quote+Destination_Table+single_quote+" AND TABLE_SCHEMA="+single_quote+SCHEMA+single_quote+";";
var Blob_Columns = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: Blob_Columns_Query}  ).execute();
Blob_Columns.next();

//Final Code Preparation

var primary_key=[];
var update_columns=[];
var No_Update_Records=[];
var Columns_with_table_name=[];
var All_Columns=[];
var cmd = "DESC TABLE "+Destination_Table;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: cmd}  );
var result1 = stmt.execute();
while(result1.next() )
{
  if(result1.getColumnValue(6)==''Y'')
  {
        primary_key.push( ''A.''+result1.getColumnValue(1)+''=B.''+result1.getColumnValue(1) );
  }
  else
  {
        update_columns.push( ''A.''+result1.getColumnValue(1)+''=B.''+result1.getColumnValue(1) );
        No_Update_Records.push( ''A.''+result1.getColumnValue(1)+''<>B.''+result1.getColumnValue(1) );
  }
  Columns_with_table_name.push( ''B.''+result1.getColumnValue(1) );
  All_Columns.push( result1.getColumnValue(1) );
}
// combine
All_Columns=All_Columns.join(",");
Columns_with_table_name=Columns_with_table_name.join(",");
update_columns=update_columns.join(",");
primary_key=primary_key.join(" AND ");
No_Update_Records=No_Update_Records.join(" OR ");

var Final_Command=  "MERGE INTO "+Destination_Table+" AS A USING (SELECT "+Blob_Columns.getColumnValue(1)+" FROM "+Source_Table+") AS B ON "+primary_key+
                    "\\nWHEN MATCHED AND "+No_Update_Records+" THEN UPDATE SET "+update_columns +
                    "\\nWHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT ( "+All_Columns+" ) VALUES ( "+ Columns_with_table_name +" );"
var Delete_Load=snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: Final_Command}  ).execute();   
Delete_Load.next();
return "Rows_Inserted:- "+Delete_Load.getColumnValue(1)+"\\tRows_Updated:- "+Delete_Load.getColumnValue(2);

';
```

I tried this:

```
// Initialize parameters
var single_quote = "\\'";
var SCEHMA = "'" + TBL_SCHEMA_NAME + "'";
var Destination_Table = "'" + SF_TBL + "'";
var Source_Table = "'@" + STG_NAME + "/" + FILE_PATH + " (file_format => " + single_quote + FILE_FRMT + single_quote + ")'";
```

I figured if I could differentiate between a standard column and a column with a space, it would work, but snowflake does not like the way I'm defining the parameters. I tried a number of variations of this, but all roads lead to Rome.

EDIT::
This is what i've updated a bit. Still no luck column names with spaces or characters. In addition. when we do incremental load, i noticed that it also updates the load_date for all records since the new load_date feeded from ADF is different. I'd like to prevent that and only update the load date on new inserts and updated records. I'd like all other records to remain the same.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE @{activity('LookupSchemaName').output.firstRow.TARGET_SCHEMA}.BLOBTOSNOWFLAKE(STG_NAME VARCHAR, FILE_PATH VARCHAR, FILE_FRMT VARCHAR, TBL_SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR, SF_TBL VARCHAR)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$

// Initialize parameters
var single_quote = '\'';
var SCEHMA = TBL_SCHEMA_NAME;
var Destination_Table = SF_TBL;
var Source_Table = "@" + STG_NAME + "/" + FILE_PATH + " (file_format => " + single_quote + FILE_FRMT + single_quote + ")";

// First script to count number of columns and append $ to support querying external stage files
var Blob_Columns_Query = "SELECT CONCAT(" + single_quote + "$" + single_quote +
    ", LISTAGG(CONCAT(ORDINAL_POSITION, " + single_quote + " AS " + single_quote + ", COLUMN_NAME), " + single_quote + ",$" + single_quote +
    ") WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION)) \n FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS \n WHERE TABLE_NAME = " +
    single_quote + Destination_Table + single_quote + " AND TABLE_SCHEMA = " + single_quote + SCEHMA + single_quote + 
    single_quote + " AND COLUMN_NAME NOT IN ( "'LOAD_DATE') "+ single quote + ";";
var Blob_Columns = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: Blob_Columns_Query}).execute();
Blob_Columns.next();

// Final Code Preparation
var primary_key = [];
var update_columns = [];
var No_Update_Records = [];
var Columns_with_table_name = [];
var All_Columns = [];
var cmd = "DESC TABLE " + Destination_Table;
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: cmd});
var result1 = stmt.execute();
while (result1.next()) 
{
    if (result1.getColumnValue(6) == 'Y') 
    {
        primary_key.push('A.' + result1.getColumnValue(1) + '=B.' + result1.getColumnValue(1));
    } 
    else 
    {
        update_columns.push('A.' + result1.getColumnValue(1) + '=B.' + result1.getColumnValue(1));
        No_Update_Records.push('A.' + result1.getColumnValue(1) + '<>B.' + result1.getColumnValue(1));
    }
    Columns_with_table_name.push('B.' + result1.getColumnValue(1));
    All_Columns.push(result1.getColumnValue(1));
}

// Check if LOAD_DATE column exists in All_Columns
var hasLoadDateColumn = All_Columns.includes('LOAD_DATE');


// Combine
All_Columns = All_Columns.join(",");
Columns_with_table_name = Columns_with_table_name.join(",");
update_columns = update_columns.join(",");
primary_key = primary_key.join(" AND ");
No_Update_Records = No_Update_Records.join(" OR ");

var Final_Command = `
MERGE INTO ${Destination_Table} AS A 
USING (
    SELECT ${Blob_Columns.getColumnValue(1)}, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS LOAD_DATE 
    FROM ${Source_Table}
) AS B 
ON ${primary_key}
WHEN MATCHED AND ${No_Update_Records} THEN UPDATE SET ${update_columns}
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (${All_Columns}) VALUES (${Columns_with_table_name});
`;

var Deleta_Load = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: Final_Command}).execute();
Deleta_Load.next();

return "Rows_Inserted:- " + Deleta_Load.getColumnValue(1) + "\tRows_Updated:- " + Deleta_Load.getColumnValue(2);

$$;
```

Comment: Hi - not related to your main issue but if you changed your code block delimiters from single quotes to $$ it would mean you didn't have to repeat every single quote in your code and would probably make your life easier

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the issue is - if you put quotes round each column name then there shouldn't be an issue and you don't need to worry about what a column name contains (assuming it doesn't contain a single quote. As you can reference your source columns positionally (i.e. $1) rather than by name this only seems to be an issue with the SF target columns and can't you make sure they aren't created with names that require quoting?

Comment: @NickW sorry. did not see your comment till i logged in. I updated the original question -- Still no luck column names with spaces or characters. In addition. when we do incremental load, i noticed that it also updates the load_date for all records since the new load_date feeded from ADF is different. I'd like to prevent that and only update the load date on new inserts and updated records. I'd like all other records to remain the same.